# CLI based node chat app

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, npm, server

I am wondering how I would go about making a command line interface chat app using nodejs. I could just make one using http and then use something like phantomjs to read it back into the terminal. However I am sure that there is a better way to do this. 
Thanks!
-Zoe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/real-time-chat-with-nodejs-readline-socketio--cms-20953

> Node.js has an under-appreciated module in its standard library that is surprisingly useful. The Readline module does what it says on the box: it reads a line of input from the terminal. This can be used to ask the user a question or two, or to create a prompt at the bottom of the screen.

You can then use Socket.io as the server.

Comment: oops, meant to mark this one right. They must have switched places because they where submitted so close together.

Answer (score 1):

Node.js is a **server-based** Javascript.

It will be better if you can use another programming language for client and **connect** it to NodeJS Server.

Comment: Than you that is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: You are welcome. In addition, if you write a client on NodeJS, user who will use the client must have NodeJS installed on his computer.

You can write it on any other programming language (C/C++, Python, Java, Haxe, etc.) and export the executable file for the latest user.

There is no restriction like "Client and Server programs must run on same language or same platform".

Comment: Cool, I think anyone using this will have nodejs on there computer. Just out of curiosity, how would I go about creating this without socket.io? like if I wanted to write my own chat server? thanks again!

Comment: Here is an "Chat server" example for NodeJS: https://gist.github.com/creationix/707146

You should save it as .js file and run from terminal (cmd) like this:
`node yourfile.js`